# How can I make Gridview get filled AFTER save is clicked?

Tags: android, gridview

Im developing a contacts app, and for now Ive been trying to get this drawables from the array get uploaded into the Gridview on the main screen AFTER the save mosaic button is clicked in the mosaic creation screen.

the floating action button (red plus button) on the mosaicListScreen (main screen) leads to the MosaicCreationScreen). the user hypothetically uploads the image and enters the mosaic name then saves using the save mosaic button, as can be seen in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYZon.png)

For now, before I focus on uploading image and letting the user create their own unique mosaics (groups), Im testing the Gridview updating with some drawables, which are listed in the array as can be seen in the code below.

The issue thats occuring is as soon as the user clicks the floating action button on the main screen, it updates the gridview with the drawables listed in the array of the MosaicCreation Screen, THEN it goes to the MosaicCreationScreen, and when save mosaic button is clicked on the MosaicCreationScreen, the intent goes to the main screen as its supposed to do, except the gridview will have nothing on it.

so its like its doing the opposite of whats supposed to happen in steps.

here is my code for the two screens:

```
    public class mosaicsListScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static mosaicsListScreen theScreen; //this variable is used in the MosaicCreationScreen to point to this screen to find the GridView by id
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        theScreen = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mosaics_list_screen);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.createMosaicButton);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MosaicCreationScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is the code for the MosaicCreationScreen (the one that opens after user clicks floating action button from mosaicListScreen (main screen))

```
    public class MosaicCreationScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mosaic_creation_screen);

        final GridView mosaicList = (GridView) mosaicsListScreen.theScreen.findViewById(R.id.mosaicList);
        mosaicList.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); //this line of code displays the mosaics on mosaicListScreen

        Button saveNewMosaicButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveNewMosaicButton);
        saveNewMosaicButton.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //mThumbIds.notify();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mosaicsListScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                //mosaicList.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); //this displays the mosaics on mosaicListScreen, it logically should go here, however "this" causes an error saying ImageAdapter (android.content.Context) in ImageAdapter cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)
                Toast.makeText(mosaicsListScreen.theScreen, "Mosaic Created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

/*        mosaicList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(mosaicsListScreen.theScreen, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

        //this array holds the drawables that would appear on the Gridview
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.family,
                R.drawable.project
        };
    }
}
```

Here are the XML for the layouts:

content_mosaics_list_screen.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="codesages.mosaic.mosaicsListScreen"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_mosaics_list_screen">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/create_a_mosaic_or_pick_from_the_mosaics_created"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/deleteMosaicButton"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/mosaicList"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/holdMosaictoDeleteLabel"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/deleteMosaicButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_mosaics_list_screen.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="codesages.mosaic.mosaicsListScreen">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/createMosaicButton"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_mosaics_list_screen" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_mosaic_creation_screen.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="codesages.mosaic.MosaicCreationScreen"
    android:focusable="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mosaicNametextField"
        android:hint="Mosaic Name"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save New Mosaic"
        android:id="@+id/saveNewMosaicButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/uploadMosaicImageButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Upload Mosaic Image"
        android:id="@+id/uploadMosaicImageButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mosaicNametextField"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

mosaicList.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
thats what appears to be creating the mosaics. if i comment this out, i wont see anything in the gridview.

however, i believe that should be inside the saveNewMosaicButton onClick, but I am getting an error that says "saying ImageAdapter (android.content.Context) in ImageAdapter cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)"

[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9NTa.png) is an image example of what the desired result should be. however whats happening right now is as ive stated, as soon as the floating action button is clicked, the mosaics are created, THEN it takes you to the creation screen, in which wehn i click save mosaics, it actually erases the mosaics...a job of the trash icon which is too soon to function for now heh.

appreciate help on this

Comment: "this" causes an error - that's because "this" is not the Context but the anonymous OnClickListener. Use something like "MyActivity.this"

Comment: @0X0nosugar Ive tried this: mosaicList.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mosaicsListScreen.theScreen.this)); but it says class name expected here even though im calling the mosaicListScreen through theScreen variable to point to that screen.

Comment: You really only need to use "mosaicsListScreen.this" to refer to the current Activity (at least that's how many people seem to do it ) If anything, I'd expect. "mosaicsListScreen.theScreen" to work. But somehow I like the other approach better.

Comment: @0X0nosugar ive tried both of them, and unfortunately I see no drawables from the array on the gridview of mosaicListScreen :/ Btw, mosaicsListScreen wont work by itself, thats why I used theScreen variable to point to the mosaicsListScreen in another screen in order to fetch the gridview, cause the gridview id is in mosaicListScreen, so it needs that variable as a reference otherwise I was getting errors.

Comment: But at least it does not crash any more ;-) I must confess up to now I did not read all of your code. Will do so now and be back.

Comment: @0X0nosugar i guess lol, I would love a suggestion that can get me progressing forward, as I have been meddling and staring at this for days now. I mean the "theScreen" variable was something that took me so many hours trial and error until I figured to create a variable pointer from the main screen to the creation screen, because it was giving a null value without it. Now with this issue I find myself in a similar position yet again, and even though it seems its a simple thing, I just cant get my hand on it lol

Comment: All right, I really should have tried to understand your app structure earlier. My bad. I think your way of accessing the ListView in mosaicsListScreen from MosaicCreationScreen will not work. But we will get this sorted out.

Comment: Please add the layout xml for both Activities

Comment: @0X0nosugar added the XML for both activities

Comment: took a while but I think this will work. If you have questions, please ask, but I need to be off the next minutes.

Comment: @0X0nosugar ok im gonna check it fast now, thanks for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have

```
public static mosaicsListScreen theScreen;
```

in your first `Activity` which you use to fill the `ListView` in this first `Activity`. This is a dangerous approach because the `Activity` instance referenced by this variable may be destroyed, for example if you're doing work in your second `Activity` (e.g. downloading images) which uses much memory, but also if the user somehow triggers a configuration change.

As you are calling `finish()` after starting the second `Activity`, you even tell the system that the first `Activity` may be destroyed. The only reason you did not get a NPE is that the system destroys the finished `Activity` not instantly but as soon as it seems a good idea to do so.

All in all, you need a way to safely transmit information from one `Activity` to the other. In your case, I think you would like to send the Uri of the selected images ( or for now, send the resource id of the selected drawables). Both can be accomplished by using `Intent` extras.

Basically, there are two options:

- use `startActivityForResult()` and override `onActivityResult()` to obtain the desired information for the first `Activity`
- simply start the first `Activity` from the second `Activity` once you have the result and use `getIntent()` in the first `Activity` (e.g. in `onCreate()`) to check for results

No matter what you do, always access UI elements like the `ListView` in the `Activity` to which they belong!

If you choose the second option, your first `Activity` could look like this:

```
public class mosaicsListScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String THUMB_IDS = "someuniquestring";

private GridView            mosaicList;
private ArrayList<Integer>  mThumbIds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mosaics_list_screen);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.createMosaicButton);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MosaicCreationScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    fillThumbIds();

    mosaicList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mosaicList);
    // Note: Adapter code in this Activity
    mosaicList.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}

private void fillThumbIds()
{
    mThumbIds = new ArrayList();
    // somehow get older thumb ids if necessary (from database?)
    // and add to ArrayList like this:
    mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.family);
    mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.project);

    // assuming we transmit resource id's: use an int array with the Intent
    int[] newThumbIds = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra(THUMB_IDS);
    if (newThumbIds != null)
    {
        // loop through the array to add new thumb ids
        for (int i = 0; i < newThumbIds.length; i++) {
            mThumbIds.add(newThumbIds[i]);
        }
    }
}

// Adapter code goes here
// Note: thumbIds no longer as array but as ArrayList!
}
```

In the second `Activity`, you put the selected thumb ids as `Intent` extra as follows:

```
saveNewMosaicButton.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mosaicsListScreen.class);
        // if 'myNewThumbs' is the int array with the new thumb ids
        intent.putExtra(mosaicsListScreen.THUMB_IDS, myNewThumbs);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        }

});
```

Comment: Im getting some issues. starting with public static final THUMB_IDS = "someuniquestring"; it tells me "cannot resolve symbol THUMB_IDS". And in the mosaicCreationScreen (second activity that is), its not recognizing mosaicsListScreen in this code: intent.putExtra(mosaicListScreen.THUMB_IDS, myNewThumbs);
that is why I used "theScreen" variable originally because of this issue. it wont reognize other activities

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - sorry there was a typo: it should be `intent.putExtra(mosaicsListScreen.THUMB_IDS, myNewThumbs);` Does it still not find the variable after you correct the typo?

Comment: ok so I had to give it a String type in order for it to accept that public static final String THUMB_IDS = "";
Also, the mthumbIds array...i tried making it an arrayList, and the drawable are not being accepted for some reason, saying cannot resolve symbol. heres how i changed the array to arrayList: private ArrayList mThumbIds = new ArrayList(){
                drawable.family,
                drawable.project
        };

UPDATE: mosaicsListScreen is now found in second activity

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - my bad, forgot "String" for THUMB_IDS (unfortunately there's no code check here on SO). Added example how to fill ArrayList.

Comment: btw if Im not mistaken, private ArrayList<Integer>  thumbIds; is supposed to be mThumbIds right?

Comment: the public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }
tells me now that I had to change length to modCount, and now modCount has an error saying modCount has protected access in java.util.AbstractList
      This is from the Image Adapter class, unless this count is no longer needed
UPDATE: i commented it out, but the ImageAdapter class said its necessary to have an Abstract method, so I used the suggestion but this time it removed the previous return and just did return 0;

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - I'd say you have to change `length` to `size()` in order to keep getting the number of elements in the list. And of course in `getView()` you should write `imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds.get(position) );`

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - `getCount()` will always be called. AFAIK if you return 0, you'll never see anything but an empty list.

Comment: I see. size worked fine. although, i get kinda confused with overrides. whether I remove or keep it above the getCount(), it doesnt say an error, but what is override here necessary for?

Comment: Adapters have a lot of empty methods which have to be implemented (like `getCount()` and `getView()` ) or may be implemented if necessary(like `getItem()` ) .

Comment: The annotation `@Override` is simply a means of letting the IDE know that you think it's an override so it can check if you forgot anything. If you want to override but use a wrong parameter or return type, you'll get a warning with the annotation.

Comment: I see, so thats its purpose. 
Everything looks good on the mosaicListScreen code, but the newThumbIds in the mosaicCreationScreen is not being accepted in the second parameter. i tried doing it like the THUMBS_IDS string by calling mosaicsListScreen.newThumbIds but it still sees it as cannot resolve symbol

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - I suppose that's because I did nothing to declare/ initialize myNewThumbs. It is simply a placeholder for your values. As a first step you can simply set it up like `int myNewThumbs = {  R.drawable.family,  R.drawable.project};` Later on, you will want to replace it with real values as the user is allowed to upload images.

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - the point of using Intents to communicate is that you should avoid accessing variables from another Activity if they are not  final. Your second Activity needs some means of keeping track of uploaded images, e.g. an array. But this array should be private to the Activity.

Comment: awesome, I just tested it out and its doing pretty much what i needed :)
just one more curious thing;         if (newThumbIds != null)
        {
            mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.family);
            mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.contacts);
        }
I decided to try these two in the mosaicListScreen, while the new declaration you told me to declare in mosaicCreationScreen for the int myNewThumbs[] = { R.drawable.family, R.drawable.project}; has different second drawable from the array list one. yet, the array list drawables are the ones being created when i hit save.

Comment: so i guess my question is, is there a need to even put anything in the newThumbId int[]?

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - First: another typo. it's int[] not int. Guess you noticed already. About the other question: suppose you have no old values, e.g. on first run. So they would not be added in `fillThumbIds()` Then you'd only be able to display something if the user selected new images in the second Activity.

Comment: Ok I understand. btw, there will be no database involved, as my teammate suggested we use system files to store the mosaics (or groups in this case). is that possible?

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - please check the for loop in the updated `fillThumbIds()` and best use different drawables for old and new images

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - Of course you don't need a database. There are other storage options

Comment: great to hear that :)
one last thing, i was hoping the for loop would apply everytime the user clicks save a group that it would save a group/mosaic one at a time in the gridview. 
now, it would simply output them 2 at once (since i use 2 drawables here for testing). but assuming we have 2 drawables in the array anyways, how do i make it so that a drawable is saved once at a time? and so whenever i close the app and reopen it (without rerunning the program) the saved mosaic is retained?

Comment: @masterofcatastrophe - how about writing some method `saveNewImage(int)` and calling it for each new image in the for loop? Like I said, you have various options for saving data. At first (test only!!!) you could go for a `private static ArrayList<Integer> mData` in mosaicsListScreen to store selected images. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for storage options

Comment: ok i will seek to it and see what happens. Much thanks for the help throughout the night, Im sure I wouldve been stuck here still at square 1 otherwise..
Ill mark the question as solved :)